# How to correct warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, gcc, destructor

I have a class with a buffer which is later filled from reading a file:

```
char* m_buffer;
```

... and in the class destructor I perform the following:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i < m_size; i++) {
  delete (char*)m_buffer[i];
}
delete m_buffer;
```

I am receiving a compiler warning at `delete (char*)m_buffer[i]`:

> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

I've read a few of the other questions regarding similar issues but I'm not able to understand how those solutions apply.

**Update** *and to answer comments*:
`m_buffer` is initialized as follows:

```
m_buffer = new char[m_size];
```

Comment: `m_buffer[i]` is `char`. What kind of object does `m_buffer` point to in the destructor? Also, consider using `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: Yes,you should delete a pointer,don't convert a char to pointer... char sizeof is 1,pointer maybe 4 or 8...

Comment: Assuming you allocated memory ala `m_buffer = new char[n];`,  you don't need to `delete` each character in the buffer to which `m_buffer` points separately: just `delete[] m_buffer`, or better yet - use a `std::string` *by value*.

Comment: @juanchopanza: `char` ???  ...I'm reading a file using `std::ifstream` and declare `m_buffer = new char[m_size]`.

Comment: So, it points to a newed array of `char`. In that case, the first posted answer is correct.

Comment: @TonyD: I understood that simply `delete[] mbuffer` only deletes the pointer to the memory allocated for the array, not the individual pointers (which are still taking up stack space ???).

Comment: Ah, okay, so its a bit different because the array is *newed*.

Comment: @IAbstract: your understanding's wrong: the actual pointer `m_buffer` should be deallocated when the object containing it is, whether that's because it's a local variable going out of scope or because it's a dynamically allocated variable being `delete`d; either way, you don't have to separate deallocate every data member of the class containing `m_buffer`.  *"not the individual pointers"* - why pointer***s*** plural?  `m_buffer` is ostensibly one pointer to an array of `char`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `m_buffer` is an array then simply use:

```
delete [] m_buffer;
```

There is no need to individually delete its elements.

Comment: "There is no need...", and it would be an error to do so.

Comment: @juanchopanza Rigth. Wrong choise of words :)

Answer (score 5):

`delete` is intended to free an object allocated by new. So the important question is, how do you allocate `m_buffer`?
In your current code, it seems to be an array, because you iterate over the elements of one and cast every element to a `char *` before deleting it.
If you allocated `m_buffer` with `new m_buffer[m_size]`, then the correct way would be `delete[] m_buffer`.